# I want to set up a server that's cross compatible with all platforms what should I do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need a Minecraft server solution. I want to be able to play Minecraft with my grandchildren and my daughter and possibly my son if he's still interested. They all play on different platforms my daughter plays on a PlayStation my grandchildren play on tablets my son plays on a laptop I play on a PC and a tablet randomly.

I don't care if I have to pay money for a server as long as it isn't too much what is the best solution for this? We want a private semi private actually server so we don't have to deal with other people then we don't know and I'm not asking for configuration options I just want to know where I would go or what I would do to set up a server like this?

Comment: If you're kids/grandchildren are playing on consoles/mobile devices, then they are using [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition].  You said you and your son play on a PC/laptop, which means you could _potentially_ be playing the Java _or_ Bedrock edition.  Do you know which one you are using?

Answer (score 1):

To enable cross-play of ALL platforms, you will need a Java Edition server and set up a [GeyserMC](https://geysermc.org/) proxy to enable all Bedrock Edition players to join.

If you decide to pick a paid solution, [Aternos](https://support.aternos.org/hc/en-us/articles/360051047631-Geyser) offers hosting Paper/Spigot with a Geyser plugin (pick Paper, it's more modern and robust than currently rather antiquated Spigot). You might even try it with Aternos' free hosting plan, but the performance of their free servers is abhorrent. It should also be possible from other hosting services, though the installation of Geyser will be less streamlined.

If you prefer to do it without recurring fees, you'll need to set up a regular Java Edition server on a home PC, alongside with GeyserMC standalone proxy. Players of Java Edition will connect to your server directly, Bedrock - regardless of the platform - to the proxy.